# how do you run reactjs without babel

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

We were given the following example which did not include babel.  How do I make it run without babel?

I use http-server -c-1 to start the npm server. Without babel I get a blank page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>hello</title>
      <script src="react/react.js"></script>
      <script src="react/react-dom.js"></script>
      <!--  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>-->
   <head>
   <body>
      <div id='container'>
      <div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
         <h1>Hello1 React</h1>,
         document.getElementById('container')
      );
   </script>
```

Comment: babel transpiles jsx to js so this kind of doesn't make sense

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl try writting jsx here to see what it compiles down to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make this example run without babel. Babel is the library that takes your `text/jsx` script and transforms it to plain javascript that your browser can parse and run.

You could however not use JSX and instead use `React.createElement('h1', ...` to create your react application. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html). But I would not recommend it.